# VSTS error: "Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Unable to create directory '{p}'

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I have created a folder on my localhost and shared it by giving all the permissions.

Now inside the Build Definition, i have used the **"Publish Artifact"** and configured it as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

**Error:** I am getting error during the build process to publish the artifact on the respective location. The error is shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that `localhost` represents **the current machine**? When you run a command on a build agent, `localhost` is the build agent, not your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Publish Artifact build task runs on a build agent. That build agent cannot address a file share on your localhost as `\\localhost\something`. You should use the name of your host which is available on the network, e.g. `\\mylaptop\publicshare`.

In fact, if the build agent is a VSTS hosted agent, it will not be able to see your file share unless it is visible on the internet. Basically, this is what the error message is about:

> If directory is a file share, please verify the share name is correct, the share is online, and the current process has permission to access the share.